# Bootstrap 4 clickable/hover Navbar Dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

A few weeks ago I tried to find a solution to have a bootstrap 4 navbar Dropdown with a +/- on small devices. With the help on here it was all sorted out. But I have got a little bit of a tricky issue.
Each link in the Top Navigation should have its own Page. So below I have "About Us". On a full size screen I want to open the Subnavigation "on hover" and when clicking on About Us get the About Us Page. On small Screens I want the + and - shown at the end of "About Us" and when you click on + it should open the Subnavigation, but when you click on "About Us" then it should show the "About Us" Page.
I noticed that if I add a href to the "About Us" then this gets ignored. It looks like that it gets ignored because of the data-toggle in the `<a>` tag. If I remove it then it works, but obviously now the click on the plus does not open the Subnavigation instead it goes to "About Us" which makes perfect sense because the Plus is part of the a tag.

How would this be normally achieved and what should be the appropriate behaviour? I hope somebody can point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

```css
.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f067";
}

.show > .dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
  content: "\f068";
}
.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  display: flex;
}
.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
  border: none;
}

/* 
 * I inflated [data-toggle]'s specificity by adding .dropdown-toggle to it as for 
 * some reason SO is loading bootstrap.min.css after the custom CSS
 * but you can use the CSS I posted in the answer if it's loaded after bootstrap.css
 * see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/wy46msvh/
 */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Navbar Top -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom navbar-light">
  <div class="container justify-content-between">

    <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button Menu -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler  mr-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbarMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Navbar links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbarMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <!-- Link -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>

        <!-- Dropdown About Us-->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="fab fa-jenkins d-lg-none d-xl-none" aria-hidden="true"></i> About  
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check below snippset. I did some changes to styles. Check whether your requirements meet.

- I suggest that put a 'About us' link in to sub menu rather than putting 'href' to main menu. Check snippet.

```css
.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
            font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
            font-weight: 900;
            content: "\f067";
            }

            .show > .dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
            content: "\f068";
            }
            .dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"] {
            display: flex;
            }
            .dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
            border: none;
            }

            .dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
                font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
                font-weight: 900;
                content: "";
            }

            .show > .dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
                content: "";
            }

            .dropdown-menu.show {
                display: none !important;
            }

            li.nav-item.dropdown:hover > div.dropdown-menu {
                display: block !important;
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                .dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
                    border: none;
                }
                .dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
                    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
                    font-weight: 900;
                    content: "\f067";
                }
                .dropdown-toggle::after {
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin-left: .255em;
                    vertical-align: .255em;
                    content: "";
                    border-top: .3em solid;
                    border-right: .3em solid transparent;
                    border-bottom: 0;
                    border-left: .3em solid transparent;
                }

                li.nav-item.dropdown:hover > div.dropdown-menu {
                    visibility: hidden;
                }

                .dropdown-menu.show {
                    display: block !important;
                    visibility: visible !important;
                }

                .show > .dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
                    content: "\f068"
                }
            }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Navbar Top -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom navbar-light">
            <div class="container justify-content-between">

                <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button Menu -->
                <button class="navbar-toggler  mr-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbarMenu">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Navbar links -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbarMenu">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <!-- Link -->
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>

                        <!-- Dropdown About Us-->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fab fa-jenkins d-lg-none d-xl-none" aria-hidden="true"></i> About
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About Us</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your advice. I tried it out, but noticed that when I click on the Plus sign the About open, when I click on the Minus about Subnavi disappears but it is still expanded and only closes when I go to another Main Navigation point. I am also not sure that I like to have twice About in that Menu... Is it possible to work?

Comment: **adding twice About o menu** - I think that is ok. Since the About us main menu is a drop down, having another link to about us page in the sub nav is ok.          **Subnavi disappears but it is still expanded** - can you explain it bit more in detail.(Sorry about it, i didn't understand what is exactly happening) When i click the minus subnav is closing.